# SQL AVG OVER all observations

Tags: sql, impala

I can create a new variable using `OVER`:

```
SELECT *,
AVG(my_variable) OVER (PARTITION BY var1, var2) as agg_view_of_my_variable
FROM table
```

How can I do this if I want the overall average, i.e. not partitioned by any variable? Basically a new column containing only one unique value `AVG(my_variable)`.

I am using Impala SQL, but I don't think it will matter for this question.

Comment: Remove `PARTITION BY var1, var2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT t.*,
       AVG(my_variable) OVER (PARTITION BY var1, var2) as agg_view_of_my_variable
FROM table t
```

As written, this breaks the data into groups defined by unique values of `var1` and `var2`.  The average is calculated within each group.

If you want the overall average, then you don't want to partition the data into any groups.  That is simply represented by leaving out the `partition by` part of the expression:

```
SELECT t.*,
       AVG(my_variable) OVER () as agg_view_of_my_variable
FROM table t;
```

In your environment, a subquery might be faster:

```
select t.*, x.overall_avg
from table t cross join
     (select avg(my_variable) as overall_avg from t) x;
```

If this is faster, it is because of a poor implementation of window functions.  The issue is that all the data is moved to one node because there is no `partition by`.  This is not actually necessary, but some optimizers do not consider alternatives.

Comment: @SAFEX . . . The table alias is not required, but it is a good idea.  I edited the answer with an alternative that might be faster in your environment.